# Probability of an event with multiple conditions

Tags: conditional-probability, poisson-process

Could you inform me please, how can I calculate conditioned probability of several events?

I have 3 events A, B, C; I know P(B|C) and I want calculate P(A|B,C). Is it possible?

In the special case B,C~Pois(2) and A~Pois(0.3*2) is a splitting of B. 
I would find P( A(10)=2 | B(10)= 5, C(3)=2 ). I can't find any formula that could help me. Thanks in advance.

---

Given a Poisson process, I know that P(N(s) | N(t)=n) with s Binomial(n, s/t). Is it also true when I have 2 different PP? In this case the solution could be found as follow:

p=0.3, λ=2 ;
A(t)~PP(pλt)
B(t)~PP(λ*t).

P( A(10)=2 | B(10)=5, B(3)=2 ) = P( A(10)=2, B(10)=5, B(3)=2 ) / P( B(10)=5, B(3)=2 )=
P( A(10)=2 ) * P( B(10)=5 | A(10)=2 ) * P( B(3)=2 | A(10)=2, B(10)=5 ) / P( B(10)=5, B(3)=2 )

I can calculate P( A(10)=2 ), P( B(10)=5, B(3)=2 ).
But what about P( B(10)=5 | A(10)=2 ) and P( B(3)=2 | A(10)=2, B(10)=5 ) ?

Comment: Use Baye's rule. $P(A|B,C) = \frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B,C)} = \frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B|C)P(C)}$. You can decompose the numerator into conditional probabilities depending on which probabilities are known.

Comment: The problem is that I can calculate only P(B|C) and I haven't found any rule for P(B|A,C) or P(C|A,B). Could you help me?

Comment: You must know something about $A$ relative to $B$ and $C$, right? You make some reference to Poisson splitting in your problem statement, but it is not very clear.

Comment: I'm sorry it was my mistake. I'm talking about Poisson processes. I'm going to update the question.

Comment: A, B and C are 3 Poisson processes. A is one obtained from the others by splitting. I'm dealing with this problem: there is a bank where people arrive according to a poisson process with rate 2. People who arrive are divided into men and women, the first with probability 0,3 (according to a Bernoulli). What is the probability that 2 males arrive at the time 10 (in the interval[0,10]) knowing that 5 people arrived at time 10 (in the interval[0,10]), 3 of which between the time 4 7 (in the interval[4,7])?

Comment: Can you help me?